# Creating groups and signing up users assigned to the group - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building out a SaaS application that allows an individual to signup and create an exclusive Group. The admin will then be able to add people to the group by e-mailing them (this will be used primarily internally by companies).

Unfortunately, I'm quite new to Rails and thereby not too sure where to begin.

All groups should be mutually exclusive and users should only be able to belong to one group.

Any suggestions of where to begin in terms of the Group / user relationship?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you have chance to do something? Then will be easy to direct you right way

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the relationship between Users and Groups, it will be a one (Group) to many (Users) relationship.  Bringing rails into context, you can take a look at [ActiveRecord associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to give yourself the right knowledge about the types of functionality that's exposed.  Everyone user `:belongs_to` only one Group, and Groups `:has_many` Users.  If you need a primer on database relationships, you can check out any primer like [this](http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1tox.html) or any link you can find with some diligent googling.

You can try out some things and come back once you have something going, then others will be able to help you out more.  If you are REALLY new to Rails, you can check out and try the running example [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).  Good luck.